# Checking if a value is contained in an array in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have an if statement like so:

```
<c:if test="${id == '1' || id == '2' || id == '3' || id == '4'}">
```

and I'm wondering if there is a way that I can simplify this by checking if `id` is contained within an array/list/set, sort of like

```
<c:if test="${id isContainedIn {'1','2','3','4'}}">
```

Obviously this isn't correct, but it demonstrates what I am looking for. Is there anything similar to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can create a String that contains your list, then you could use something like the following code.

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fn" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%
   pageContext.setAttribute("listString", "1234");
%>
<c:set var="id" value="3"/>
<c:if test='${fn:contains(listString, id)}'>
    Yes id is contained
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%
   ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
   list.add("one");
   list.add("two");
   list.add("three");
%>
<c:set var="list" value="<%=list%>" />
<html>
<body>
        My list is ${list}<br/>
<c:if test='${fn:contains(list, "two")}'>
        My list contains two <br/>
</c:if>
<c:if test='${fn:contains(list, ",")}'>
        My list contains , 
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

The output for the code above is

My list is [one, two, three]

My list contains two

My list contains ,

I hope it helps someone.